# Is there an iPhone application that can play music from arbitrary shoutcast server?

Tags: music

I know of private shoutcast servers that transmit music and I would like to hear from my iPhone on the go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TuneIn Radio](http://tunein.com/mobile/ios/) will let you add custom URLs (including ShoutCast server URLs) to your bookmarks list and stream from them. It will also keep your playlists in sync across multiple devices, record streams for, find local streams using your current location and more. You but it [the app store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tunein-radio/id418987775?mt=8). And when you're at your Mac, you can use their browser-based desktop app to keep listening and access your bookmarks.

To add a ShoutCast server as a custom URL use:

```
ipaddress:port/stream/x/
```

Where:

- `ipaddress` is the IP or host name of the machine hosting the ShoutCast server
- `port` is the port where ShoutCast is broadcasting on the server
- `stream` is the name of the stream from ShoutCast
- `x` is the number of the stream

Once you add the custom stream to your bookmarks it should be available from any TuneIn Radio application or their web app.

[image: Adding a custom stream to your TuneIn Radio bookmarks]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the [official SHOUTcast](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shoutcast-radio/id299647180?mt=8) app lets you add private servers, but worth a try.

[FStream](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fstream/id289892007?mt=8) is one of the best radio streamers and looking online, looks like it can open Shoutcast streams. I have used it for some other streams from local radio stations and a few other streaming sites and really liked it.

Finally, there is an app called [Tuner Internet Radio](http://itunes.apple.com/app/tuner-internet-radio/id284205617?mt=8) that looks like it can open Shoutcast streams too.

Answer (score 0):

I really like the app [**Internet Radio Box**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/internet-radio-box/id293623806) — it's $0.99, but it really worth!
I have many Shoutcast stations saved on it, and it also shows the album art!

Answer (score 0):

[Jukebox Shoutcast](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jukebox-shoutcast/id1233822279?mt=8) (It is free)

In the app **go to favourites** and click on **'+'** icon in the right top corner. And **add any kind of source**. **Radio or any media file**. It would just play it nicely.

- It plays all radio stations from Shoutcast and can categorize based on Genres.
- You can search by Station Name, Album, Artist, Genre
- You can add stations from any other third party Radio Station provide like from Radionomy, TuneIn or any other private channel host
- You can read lyrics while listening to the songs on Radios.
- You can even play downloaded songs from your library.
- Sleep Timer is a plus.
- Can personalize the app and apply themes.
- Links can be shared for the Stations and listen together.

[Jukebox Shoutcast](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jukebox-shoutcast/id1233822279?mt=8). I developed this app so that it could just do its job. and it does it quite well.

Comment: Please disclose your personal affiliation with that app. It would be helpful if you could explain why this app is better than the others mentioned, especially if it costs money.